# Editing nested values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

This is my structure and i want to, given both an user id and an item id (the first element in each entry inside the havelist - 5d2807a1eba04543f914d9da in the first entry), change the last value in the array (1 in the first case, 2 in the second case) by either increasing it in one or decreasing it in one.

these fields have no name, so when I browse to them, they are referred to as [0],[1],... [7] (the last one, the one i want to edit)

```
{
    "_id" : "david",
    "havelist" : [ 
        [ 
            "5d2807a1eba04543f914d9da", 
            "aaaa", 
            "cccc", 
            null, 
            "bbbb", 
            "2", 
            "", 
            1
        ], 
        [ 
            "5d28079eeba04543f914d62f", 
            "dddd", 
            "zzzz", 
            null, 
            "bbbb", 
            "3", 
            "", 
            2
        ], 
        [ 
            "5d2807bdeba04543f914eb25", 
            "eeee", 
            "cccc", 
            null, 
            "zzzz", 
            "3", 
            "", 
            1
        ], 
    ],
    "email" : "w@w.com",
}
```

i tried this

```
    k=USERS_COLLECTION.updateOne({'$and':[{'_id':'david'},{'havelist':{'$elemMatch':{'0':"5d2807a1eba04543f914d9da"}}}]},{'$set':{'havelist.$.7':0}})
```

in order to attribute 0 to the value

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
COLLECTION.find_one_and_update({'$and':[{'_id':'david'},{'havelist':{'$elemMatch':{'0':'5d2807a1eba04543f914d9da'}}}]},{'$set':{'havelist.$.7':0}})
```

this will succesfully change the value to 0. i'm still searching for an answer on how to increase or decrease by 1 the value.